# Add sound to play at time from NSDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, nsdatepicker

I'm creating a project which requires the user to be able to set a sound to play at a specific time and I'm currently doing that with local notification. I would like to change that to use `AVAudioPlayer`, and I was wondering, what would be the best approach?

The objects I've got at the moment are a `NSDatePicker` and a `stringFromDate` string. My aim is to create an alarm so that the user can set a time using the `NSDatePicker` and at that time the sound will go off.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use Global variable or Class variable to play the alarm.

```
@property AVAudioPlayer * player;
```

... ...

```
_player = [AVAudioPlayer alloc]...
[_player play];
```

It'll works fine for your project.